# State Machine using immutable Records in F#

Tags: recursion, f#, immutability, fsm

I have the following definiition for a State Machine in F#:

```
type MyEvent = Event1 | Event2 | Event3

type MachineState<'event when 'event:comparison> =
    {
    Transitions: Map<'event, MachineState<'event>>
    Data: int
    //...other State stuff, like parent state, entry/exit actions etc 
    }
    static member Default = {Transitions=Map.empty}

//simple helpers
let on event endState state =
    {state with Transitions = state.Transitions.Add(event, endState)}
let withData data state = {state with Data = data}
```

The idea is, given a State and an Event, I will search for the Event key in the transitions map and if found, I will return the new State, otherwise will return the current.
The states are defined like this:

```
let rec StateA =
    MachineState<_>.Default
    |> on Event1 StateB
    |> withData 5
and StateB =
    MachineState<_>.Default
    |> on Event2 StateC
    |> withData -999
and StateC =
    MachineState<_>.Default
    //|> on Event3 StateA //This actually gives a runtime error
    |> withData 84
```

This gives me two problems:
One error, FS0031, saying that StateA is part of its own definition and one warning, warn40, saying the objects will be evaluated for initialization-soundness at runtime.

I can fix the error by wrapping everything in lazy:

```
...Transitions: Map<'event, Lazy<MachineState<'event>>>...
let rec StateA =
    lazy (MachineState<_>.Default
    |> on Event1 StateB)
and StateB =
    lazy (MachineState<_>.Default
    |> on Event2 StateC)
and StateC =
    lazy (MachineState<_>.Default
    |> on Event3 StateA)
```

This doesnt fix the warning and feels kinda forced.

Is this the best way of going about this? Is there a better way to handle immutable, recursive structures? Or, more specifically, implementing a immutable HFSM?

This fiddle contains a running example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TjjeBz

Comment: Perhaps define `State` as another DU? Then a `StateMachine<'state, 'event>` is just a collection of transitions

Comment: I like @sdgfsdh's suggestion, but sticking with your current design for a moment: You're adding each transition independently to an empty machine? That doesn't seem right. Instead, I think you want some sort of fold, so you accumulate all the transitions in a single final machine.

Comment: @sdgfsdh you mean having a structure exclusively to match (State -> Event -> State)? That sounds interesting, but what do you mean having State as a DU? Each State would be a entry in the DU? brianberns Strictly speaking I dont have a "StateMachine" structure, I only have a State pointing to other States.

Comment: @fnzr can you describe what the difference between StateA and StateB? And whether transitions between states should be possible (in your current design it's only one transition from default to some other state)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy the State may carry arbitrary data. Check this fiddle, for example of it running https://dotnetfiddle.net/TjjeBz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you want to construct an immutable recursive value - an object that contains, somewhere inside, references to itself. This is hard to do in functional languages, because objects are immutable. F# can actually do this in some limited situations.

In your case, you can get the built-in F# recursive intialization to work if you use only primitive value constructors - i.e. not call any functions. I had to replace `Map` in the list of transitions with plain `list`, but this works:

```ml
type MyEvent = Event1 | Event2 | Event3

type MachineState<'event when 'event:comparison> =
  { Transitions: ('event * MachineState<'event>) list
    Data: int }
  static member Default = {Transitions=[]; Data=1}


let rec StateA = 
  { Transitions = [ Event1, StateB] 
    Data = 5 }
and StateB = 
  { Transitions = [ Event1, StateC] 
    Data = -999 }
and StateC = 
  { Transitions = [ Event1, StateA] 
    Data = 84 }
```

If you want to keep the recursive structure, but initialize it using custom functions, then you will need to have some kind of `Lazy` somewhere in the data strucutre. Your workaround works as well as any other option. I would probably make the whole `Map<..>` lazy, which maybe gives you a bit nicer syntax for the construction:

```ml
type MachineState<'event when 'event:comparison> =
  { Transitions: Lazy<Map<'event, MachineState<'event>>>
    Data: int }
  static member Default = {Transitions=lazy Map.empty; Data=1}

let on event (endState:Lazy<_>) state =
    {state with Transitions = lazy state.Transitions.Value.Add(event, endState.Value)}
let withData data state = {state with Data = data}

let rec StateA =
    MachineState<_>.Default
    |> on Event1 (lazy StateB)
    |> withData 5
and StateB =
    MachineState<_>.Default
    |> on Event2 (lazy StateC)
    |> withData -999 
and StateC =
    MachineState<_>.Default 
    |> on Event3 (lazy StateA)
    |> withData 84
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to model the `State` as simple data-term.

```ml
type State =
  | A
  | B
  | C

type Event = 
  | Event1
  | Event2
  | Event3

type StateMachine<'state, 'ev when 'state : comparison and 'ev : comparison> = 
  {
    Transitions : Map<'state, Map<'ev, 'state>>
  }
  with 
    static member Default 
      with get () = 
        {
          Transitions = Map.empty
        }

module StateMachine = 
  
  let addTransition startState ev endState sm = 
    let m = 
      sm.Transitions
      |> Map.tryFind startState
      |> Option.defaultValue Map.empty
      |> Map.add ev endState

    {
      sm with
        Transitions = 
          sm.Transitions
          |> Map.add startState m
    }

  let tryTransition state ev sm = 
    sm.Transitions
    |> Map.tryFind state
    |> Option.defaultValue Map.empty
    |> Map.tryFind ev

let myStateMachine : StateMachine<State, Event> = 
  StateMachine<State, Event>.Default
  |> StateMachine.addTransition A Event1 B
  |> StateMachine.addTransition B Event2 C
  |> StateMachine.addTransition C Event3 A

printfn "%A" (myStateMachine |> StateMachine.tryTransition A Event1)
// Some B

printfn "%A" (myStateMachine |> StateMachine.tryTransition A Event2)
// None
```

I used `Map` to store the transitions because they give more efficient look-ups, but you could use `List` instead.

---

If you want to trigger side-effects during transitions, I would suggest keeping those outside of the state representation.

For example:

```ml
let transitionAction previousState nextState = 
  match previousState, nextState with
  | (A, B) -> 
    async {
      printfn "Launching the missiles... "

      do! launchMissiles

      printfn "Game over."
    }
  | (_, _) -> 
    async {
      () // Do nothing
    }
```

---

Since the `'state` can be any type, you can also attach arbitrary data to it:

```ml
type City = 
  | London
  | NewYork
  | Tokyo

type Fuel = int

type State = City * Fuel
```

Comment: I see, but are States really simple data terms? For example, a State may have Entry and/or Exit functions. Would I have another field (inside the StateMachine<'state, 'ev>) "ExitFunctions: Map<'state, [signature]>"? And another "EntryFunctions: Map<'state, [signature]>"? That sounds messy...

Comment: F# is a multi-paradigm language, so you could model the states as objects with functions. However, the FP approach would be to keep the state as simple data-terms and then have separate functions for entry and exit side-effects.

Comment: It's not so much as side effects (entry/exit was a bad choice on my part), but actual data associated with the State. In my case specifically, the State also carries the root a tree, so when I reach the state, I make operations based on that tree. The operation itself has no side-effects.

Comment: Can you add the associated data to the `State` type?